# bug in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-boot

When I send a post request to my url, my controller manages to save the record to the database, but my ajax falls into error. What am I doing wrong?
my js code:

```
function salvarValores(){
capturarValores()
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/service/newService/service",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(( { 'cpfPessoa': cpfCliente, "descricaoServico": descricao } )),
    success: function(data){
        alert("Record successfully entered");
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("Error performing operation");
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

}

my spring boot controller

```
@PostMapping("/service/newService/service")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> newService(@RequestBody  Service service) {

    if (serviceDao.addObject(service)) {
        logger.debug("Adding data");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Data successfully saved", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    logger.error("Error to insert data in database");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Error to insert data in database", HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY);
}
```

when I click the save button, I have an alert with the message "Error performing operation" but the record has been inserted into the database correctly

Comment: what is response code of response, it can be something after the record is saved which trigger some error resulting request to fail

Comment: Why all the brackets? `data: JSON.stringify(({
      'cpfPessoa': cpfCliente,
      "descricaoServico": descricao
    })),` could be  `data: JSON.stringify({
      'cpfPessoa': cpfCliente,
      "descricaoServico": descricao
    }),`

Comment: Can you paste the serviceDao's addObject code or are you sure that it returns true if it persists the object properly ...

Comment: @mplungjan :-) The quotes (both kinds) are unnecessary, too.

Comment: Can you attach the data value (in error function). I do not know what the error is, or the error code.

Comment: my controller return status ok, the error was dataType:'json' @UmairAbid

Comment: thanks for the tip @mplungjan

Answer (score 7):

You've told jQuery that you're expecting JSON back:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  dataType: "json", // <== Here
  // ...
});
```

...but what you're returning isn't JSON:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Data successfully saved", HttpStatus.OK);
```

So when jQuery tries to parse the response (as JSON) for you, it fails.

Remove the `dataType` parameter (or set it to `"text"`). More [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).